# NSInternalInconsistencyException in tableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

[image: chatimageview]

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"MessageCellIdentifier";

    MessageTableViewCell* cell = (MessageTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[MessageTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Message* message = [self.dataModel.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([message.imgDisplay isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
        [cell setMessage:message];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setMessage:message];
    }


    return cell;

}

- (void)setMessage:(Message*)message {
CGPoint point = CGPointZero;

NSString* senderName;
BubbleType bubbleType;
if ([message isSentByUser])
{
    bubbleType = BubbleTypeRighthand;
    senderName = NSLocalizedString(@"You", nil);
    point.x = self.bounds.size.width - message.bubbleSize.width;
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
}
else
{
    bubbleType = BubbleTypeLefthand;
    senderName = message.senderName;

    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
}

// Resize the bubble view and tell it to display the message text
CGRect rect;
rect.origin = point;
rect.size = message.bubbleSize;
bubbleView.frame = rect;

if ([message.imgDisplay isEqualToString:@"image"]) {

   [bubbleView setImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",message.chatimageName] bubbleType:bubbleType];
}
else
{

    [bubbleView setText:message.text bubbleType:bubbleType];
}

// Format the message date
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[formatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];


NSString* dateString = message.date;

// Set the sender's name and date on the label
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @ %@", senderName, dateString];
[label sizeToFit];
label.frame = CGRectMake(8, message.bubbleSize.height, self.contentView.bounds.size.width - 16, 16);
}

- (int)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dataModel.messages count];
}
```

I am developing an chat application the below image shows the view of chatViewController.It is woking fine.sometimes I am getting exception as NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'.I do not know what causes problem.somebody please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not a problem , you just need to do 
    **[tableview reloadData];**
at the end of
    **- (void)setMessage:(Message*)message { }**

The problem appeared only because the cells/data that your tableview displayed was not consistent with your current data.

Read apple developer docs for more info on **delegate/datasource** to avoid further issues in your development.

All the **best** for now!

Comment: this answer is wrong. if you call `[tableView reloadData]` at the end of `setMessage` your app will have an infinite recursion b/c `setMessage` is called from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You need to call `reloadData` whenever you modify the data source which in your case is the `messages` array.

Comment: @XJones : Ya, you correct, my mistake. reloadData has to be called after modifying the data.

Comment: Accepted answer with -1 vote, That's nice!!!

Answer (score 1):

This error will happen when the data source changes without updating the `tableView` to reflect the changes. I.e. the data source is inconsistent with the `tableView`'s internal representation. The simplest way to to ensure consistency is to call `[tableView reloadData]` whenever the data source changes. You can also make more granular changes using the other `tableView` reloading methods.